# nginx serve a different file name from local server if url/file does not exist

Tags: nginx

Is there a way if file not exist to server another `app-*.js` file in other folder, example:

Go to URL: http://www.example.com/assets/build/app/app-48fee50a26.js

I am getting the following error message:

```
[error] 17788#17788: *1 open() "/var/app/assets/build/app/app-48fee50a26.js" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: , server: , request: "GET /assets/build/app/app-48fee50a26.js HTTP/1.1", host:""
```

I want to serve instead any other js file in the same folder `/var/app/assets/build/app/`, but the name of the other file can constantly change, for example `app-62a5962b0a11.js`. I was thinking about `app\-(.*)\.js`.

all the examples below does not work:

```
server {
        listen 80 default_server;
        root /var/app;

        location /assets/build/app/app\-(.*)\.js {
                try_files $uri $uri/ /assets/build/app/app\-(.*)\.js;
        }
}

server {
        listen 80 default_server;
        root /var/app;

        location /assets/build/app/app\-(.*)\.js {
                try_files $uri $uri/ /var/app/assets/build/app/app\-(.*)\.js;
        }
}


Also not working without regex to the location of the other file.

server {
        listen 80 default_server;
        root /var/app;

        location /assets/build/app/app\-(.*)\.js {
                try_files $uri $uri/ /var/app/assets/build/app/app-62a5962b0a11.js;
        }
}

server {
        listen 80 default_server;
        root /var/app;

        location /assets/build/app/app\-(.*)\.js {
                try_files $uri $uri/ /assets/build/app/app-62a5962b0a11.js;
        }
}
```

Comment: The `try_files` directive accepts URIs not pathnames. That last parameter should start with `/assets/build/app/...`

Comment: @RichardSmith, thanks, what do you mean with `last parameter` ?

Comment: I was referring to `/var/app/assets/build/app/app-62a5962b0a11.js` which looks like a pathname.

Comment: I think I have tried this, let me check again later and I will update my question with the result and I will let you know, thanks!

Comment: @RichardSmith, I have updated my question, can you please suggest ? do you think is it possible?

Comment: RichardSmith meant that you cannot use a filesystem path in the `try_files`. You must use a path relative to the `root` dir. So, the last entry in `try_files` has to be `/assets/build/app/app-62a5962b0a11.js`. And I don't think it is possible to make a wildcard match for the file to serve, since there is the issue of making a choice if multiple matches exist. However, this looks like an issue in the application architecture itself, and it would be better to fix the original issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `location` directive syntax is wrong. If you want to specify a regular expression, you must use the `~` or `~*` modifier. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location) for details.

Also, you cannot expect `nginx` to look for a random file that matches a pattern. Which means that your last attempt is closest to a working solution. For example:

```
location ~ ^/assets/build/app/app-.+\.js$ {
    try_files $uri /assets/build/app/app-62a5962b0a11.js =404;
}
```

I have added the `=404` as the default term to avoid generating a loop in the case that `app-62a5962b0a11.js` does not exist. But in general, `app-62a5962b0a11.js` must exist for proper operation. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#try_files) for `try_files` syntax.

Comment: last try :) , so even if in the folder there is only one js file exist it is not possible ?

Comment: /assets/build/app/app-(anyname).js

Comment: Not as far as I know. You may be able to do something with language extensions such as LUA (but again I do not know). Obviously, you could add a symlink to the default file which would allow you to change it outside of `nginx`.